# Three column Numpy array to a dict of tuples?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

So I am trying to find the fastest/most efficient way of performing the following transformation.

From a three column array

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.array([[1,2,3,3],[5,6,7,8],[8,7,6,5]]).T

array([[1, 5, 8],
       [2, 6, 7],
       [3, 7, 6],
       [3, 8, 5]])
```

into a dict keyed off of one column with a list of tuples as the value, as such:

```
{1:[(5,8)], 2:[(6,7)],3: [(7,6),(8,5)]}
```

Comment: Just use a `dict` comprehension, or loop.  When constructing `dict` you are in pure python territory; no `numpy` magics.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, if you are constructing a dict, a python object, then you just want to go with regular Python methods. I suggest using `.tolist()` on your array, because this converts to appropriate Python numeric types (but it *does* make an intermediate list). So from there, you just use your favorite Python dict grouping idiom:

```
result = {}
for key, *vals in arr.tolist():
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(tuple(vals))
```

If you don't want to create a potentially giant intermediate list, then you manually convert the type (here I'm assuming `int` based on your example):

```
result = {}
for row in arr:
    key, *vals = map(int, row)
    result.setdefault(key, []).append(tuple(vals))
```

Comment: If there's more elements in a row, you can replace `a, b, c` with `a, *r`, and `(b, c)` with `tuple(r)`.

Comment: @Amadan yeah might as well make it generalizable for cheap

Answer (score 1):

```
In [257]: from collections import defaultdict
In [258]: arr = np.array([[1,2,3,3],[5,6,7,8],[8,7,6,5]]).T
In [259]: arr
Out[259]: 
array([[1, 5, 8],
       [2, 6, 7],
       [3, 7, 6],
       [3, 8, 5]])
```

A defaultdict makes collecting 'related' values easy.  Just define one that makes a list value as default value.

```
In [260]: dd = defaultdict(list)
```

Then just add the elements, using the first element as key, the rest as a tuple (appended to the default []).

```
In [261]: for i in arr.tolist():
     ...:     dd[i[0]].append(tuple(i[1:]))
     ...: 
In [262]: dd
Out[262]: defaultdict(list, {1: [(5, 8)], 2: [(6, 7)], 3: [(7, 6), (8, 5)]})
```

For iteration, a list is a bit faster than an array.

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict

arr = np.array([[1,2,3,3],[5,6,7,8],[8,7,6,5]]).T
# every value of the key in your dict is a list
d = defaultdict(list)

for a in arr:
    d[a[0]].append((a[1], a[2]))

print(d)
```

Comment: I modify the answer, thanks @Amadan